# Oracle RAC VIP and SCAN IPs

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, dns, oracle-rac

I've read the Oracle RAC documentation a couple of times but SCAN and VIP are still confusing me. Can someone help me understand how this needs to be configured technically so that I can explain it my network admin.

1. VIP in Oracle RAC, should each VIP bind to the node or just require a DNS A record without allocating it to node1 or node2 and an entry in the host file?
   I know while performing Grid cluster installation Oracle will bind the VIP automatically, but should this be part of DNS assigned to one of the nodes or should it be free and unassigned?
2. Oracle SCAN IPs need to be created in DNS record; is this an A record to 3 IPs with reverse lookup or round robin way and this should not be part of hosts file?

I need to explain this to my network admin to add it on the DNS server.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, VIPs:

A VIP is a Virtual IP address, and should be defined in DNS and *not* assigned to any host or interface.  When you install GRID/ASM home, you'll specify the VIP names that were assigned in DNS.  When Oracle Clusterware starts up, it will assign a VIP to each node in the cluster.  The idea is, if a node goes down (crashes), clusterware can immediately re-assign that VIP to a new (surviving) node.  This way, you avoid TCP timeout issues.

Next, SCAN:

A SCAN (Single Client Access Name) is a special case of VIP.  The SCAN should also be defined in DNS, and *not* assigned to any host or interface.  There should be three IPs associated with the SCAN name in DNS, and the DNS entry should be defined so that one of the three IPs is returned each time DNS is queried, in a round robin fashion.

At clusterware startup time, each of the three VIPs that make up the SCAN will be assigned to a different node in the cluster.  (Except in the special case of a two node cluster, one of the nodes wil have a 2 SCAN VIPs assigned to it.)  The point of the SCAN, is that no matter how many nodes are added to or removed from the cluster, all the Net Service Name definitions in your tnsnames.ora (or LDAP equivalent) will not need to ever change, because they all refer to the SCAN, which doesn't change, regardless of how many node additions or drops are made to the cluster.

For example, in the three node cluster, you may have:

Physical and virtual hostnames/IPs assigned as follows:

```
Hostname    Physical IP    Virtual hostnmae   Virtual IP
rac1        10.1.1.1       rac1-vip           10.1.1.4
rac2        10.1.1.2       rac2-vip           10.1.1.5
rac3        10.1.1.3       rac3-vip           10.1.1.6
```

Additionally, you may have the SCAN defined as:
`rac-scan` with three IPs, `10.1.1.7, 10.1.1.8, 10.1.1.9`.  Again, the DNS definition would be defined so those IPs are served up in a round robin order.

Note that the SCAN VIPs, Host VIPs, and the Physical IPs are all in the same subnet.

Finally, though you didn't ask about it, to complete the picture, you'd also need one private, non-routable IP assigned per host, and that IP would be associated with the private interconnect.  So, you may have something like:

```
rac1-priv  172.16.1.1
rac2-priv  172.16.1.2
rac3-priv  172.16.1.3
```

Note that the '-priv' addresses should *not* be in DNS, only in the /etc/hosts file of each host in the RAC cluster.  (They are private, non-routable, and only clusterware will ever know about or use those addresses, so adding to DNS doesn't make sense.)

Note also, that '-priv' and physical IP/hostname definitions should go in /etc/hosts, and the physical IPs and VIPs should be in DNS.  So, physical IPs in both DNS and /etc/hosts, VIPs only in DNS, '-priv' addresses only in /etc/hosts.

Comment: Thank you..that really cleared lot of my queries and confusion.One last question Please correct me if I'm wrong, the Public IP , VIP, SCAN should be on same public subnet.The above example you mentioned they VIP,SCAN do not seem to be on same public subnet.

Comment: Here is my sample host file   Public
192.147.3.158 (RAC1)
192.147.3.163(RAC2) Private 10.0.0.2(RAC1)
10.0.0.3(RAC2) VIP 192.147.3.159 (RAC1-vip)
192.147.3.164(RAC2-vip)

Comment: Yes, that's correct.  The public IPs, SCAN VIPs, and Host VIPs should all be in the same subnet.  I edited my post above accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

1. not entirely sure what you mean for this, i have each VIP address created in DNS as A records assigned to the hosts, and also record them in the hosts file as well.

in answer to 2, you are correct, the SCAN IPs should not be in the hosts file. And yes 3 "A" records with reserve lookup will be enough (at least that's what has worked for me).

these are my iptables entries

## Oracle ports

## Allow access from other oracle RAC hosts

-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -p tcp -m iprange --src-range 172.28.1.90-172.28.1.97 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -p tcp -m iprange --src-range 172.28.97.91-172.28.97.93 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -p tcp -m iprange --src-range 192.168.28.91-192.168.28.93 -j ACCEPT

## Allow Multicast

-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -p udp -m iprange --src-range 172.28.1.90-172.28.1.97 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -p udp -m iprange --src-range 172.28.97.91-172.28.97.93 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -p udp -m iprange --src-range 192.168.28.91-192.168.28.93 -j ACCEPT

## Allow multicast

-A INPUT -m pkttype --pkt-type multicast -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 224.0.0.0/24 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 230.0.1.0/24 -j ACCEPT

I also needed to get our systems admin to give permissions a the firewall level to allow my nodes, their vips and the scan ips to connect via port 1521

hope this helps

Comment: I'm currently doing the installation and cluvfy -pre crinst is failing at VIP "interfaces not found".VIP is part of the host file and added to the dns server with "A" record pointing to the each nodes

Comment: Just trying to understand how VIP should be configured on DNS server and on nodes.

Comment: in my installation (just completed after a lot of grief). I have "A" records in my DNS for all the nodes, also for all the VIP nodes and 3 for the SCAN itself, there are also reserve lookup records for all of them.

in the hosts file, i have entires for the nodes and their VIPs, but not for the scan, also have entries for the private interconnects between the nodes (this is on another subnet).

what did trip me up and caused my clufy to fail was the setup of iptables, this comment is now too large so will include my iptables entries in my answer